# If statement will be ignored when a game object is set to false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project for a platform game where you as a player have to collect logs, to keep on all the fires in the level. Each campfire has a timer, which ensures that every x number of seconds the animation of the fire is changed to a numb fire. The timer of a campfire is blocked by the script, when the player has received the fire at 100%.

I created an if statement to handle if a campfire is 100% it will not decrease in amount. So I declare a boolean isFull, that will be set to true if a campfire is 100%. Then below if statement is not fired. But the problem is, when I have a second campfire in my level that is not full, it wouldn't decrease, because if campfire (1) is full, the bool is set to true and then the if statement will be ignored.

I code it with C sharp. The script is linked to each campfire.
Below block of code is positioned inside the `void Update()` of Unity.

```
// If all campfires are empty = losing
    if (campfireStatus <= 0) {
        isEmpty = true;
    } else {
        isEmpty = false; // hier zat ook een fout. hij wordt als ie leeg was en je hem dan nog wel kon aanvullen. wordt ie nu weer op false gezet, dus dat ie niet empty is
    }

    // If all campfires are full = winning
    if (campfireStatus >= 4){
        isFull = true;
    }


    timer+= Time.deltaTime;

    if (!isFull) { // dit wordt maar 1x gedaan. als er 1 vuurtje isFULL 1 is dan wordt het andere vuurtje niet meer veranderd

        if (timer > beforeDecrease) {

            timer = 0;

            if (campfireStatus != 0) {
                campfireStatus--;
                //Debug.Log ("Decrease");

                if (campfireStatus == 0) {
                    allCampfireEmpty++;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Entire code of the campfire script you can [see here](http://snippi.com/s/vf0x1k5).

Comment: Is `campfireStatus` actually tracked separately for each campfire, or once, globally, for all campfires?

Comment: I think it used global, because if one campfire set it to true, the other one will be ignored. @O.R.Mapper

Comment: Ok then - why? :) ([Kjata30's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29520672/1430156) is correct IMHO.)

Comment: I checked it one more time. If a campfire is off, it will set the `bool` of isEmpty to true. But not for the other one. So its separate from each other.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't follow object oriented practices. Your campfires should be an instance of a `Campfire` class that implements a `bool IsFull` property or field. This way, you can say for any instance of `Campfire`:

```
if (!campfire.IsFull)
// decrease campfire status
```

Comment: This is not where I am searching for. I was trying to make a foreach loop though my array of all game objects with the tag "Campfire", but this will give me an error. isFull will be red, when I paste campfire before it separate by a dot. `foreach (GameObject campfire in campfires) {if (campfireStatus >= 4) {campfire.isFull = true;} }`